# $400 electric bill traced to heater - what could be wrong with it?

Tags: electrical, hvac

Back in December/January, we got a real shocker; a $400+ electric bill. I thought there must be a billing error, so I went out to the meter, and found that not only was the number probably right, we'd used another 1000kW/h since the reading (which was about a week and a half prior). This is for a modest 1600 sqft 1.5-story house; WAY outta line. My next thought was a leech; someone hooking to our service unbeknownst to us. We turned off all the lights, computers, etc etc, leaving the service panel on, and... wait, now it's down to a crawl. OK, so it's something in the house. My wife and I were talking by cell phone, when suddenly I see the dial start its whizzing again. I asked what turned on, and she said, "well, the HVAC started a few seconds ago". Bingo. It's an all-electric home, so we have an electric heater, and when it's running the full system (not just the vent fan), it's really drawing some juice.

The heater is not original to the house (at least, it's a Lennox with logos and branding far newer than the Sears-Kenmore HWH which IS original). I can't tell you it's exact age at this moment. We replaced the filter; no change in electrical use. We REMOVED the filter; no change. We also noticed that despite the massive power draw, the system was not producing very warm air (though it is blowing pretty well). It seemed fine in October/November, but then, we had a relatively mild winter until mid-December. Whatever this is, it is NOT normal; we've had 1000+ sqft apartments and townhomes that we could heat very comfortably in the winter with $150 bills. An extra 500 sqft of house should NOT be costing $300 more to heat. As a reference, through the summer months in this home (including the hottest monthly average for August, ever), which generally produce much bigger bills than winter, we kept this same house around 75* and paid about $220/mo.

We have a home warranty agreement that would cover a fault in the HVAC unit itself, and MAY also cover wiring slipups. We picked a name of an HVAC company out of a city publication for new home owners, so we're not sure just how good they'll be. Knowing what I know right now, what would I expect to hear these guys say? My primary expectation is a short in the heating element or in the switching circuitry within the unit. If they say it's normal I'll be telling them to shove their normal up their [censored]; we've had the HVAC system off since we found the problem, using our fireplace instead, and after living in a house averaging 60*, our latest bill (including the week after the prior billing cycle) was still $250. Whatever it is, it is NOT normal.

**EDIT FROM COMMENTS:** It is a simple forced-air system with an electric heating element. The breaker marked for the heater is 220V 70A. That means that the max available wattage is 15.4kW. Running 24/7 at its max rated power for 30 days, the system would cost $1020... So maybe, just maybe, there's nothing wrong with it.

**EDIT 2:** The warranty repair guy showed up yesterday. When my wife showed him the heater unit we had, he knew exactly what she was going to say next; apparently this particular unit is infamous for its inefficiency. Nevertheless, he did a check of the system, and found that one of the 3 heating elements was disconnected. That was putting more voltage onto the other two coils, and decreased the effectiveness of the whole system, meaning we were using the same amount of power to do less work for a longer period of time. After reattaching the element, the house heated up to the thermostat setting quickly and we're noticing it's not running nearly as much. However, we should still be expecting $250-$300 bills for months that hover around freezing.

Comment: What is the amps rating of the circuit breaker feeding the heater?  If there is a short drawing more power, that more power will be heating SOMETHING.  With your house at 60F now, set the thermostat back up higher like 70F, for this test.  Run as little of everything else as you can (switch all the other breakers off, perhaps).  Read the meter before and after the test.  Report back with kWH used and time it ran.  This should get an approximation of the amperage involved.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question to remove the rant so that it doesn't get closed as non-constructive. Also, be sure to include what kind of heating system. Is it a heat pump, and is it on emergency heat (does the outside compressor turn on)? When you said the winter got cold, what was the average outdoor temperature?

Comment: Where do you live? Have you lived there through a heating season or is this your first one? What temperature do you have the house set at? How well insulated is the house? (I ask as if it's a normally mild region and it's unusually cold, $400 for electric heat seems quite reasonable...but I agree, to save $$$, stick with the fireplace)

Comment: Even if something is wrong with your heater, all that energy ended up somewhere, most likely as heat within your house. So after you diagnose and fix any problems with the heater, go looking for heat loss. Open windows? Missing insulation? Etc.

Comment: Does the heater have a label that says how many watts it draws?  Do you have a clamp on ammeter?

Comment: If your fireplace is not vented with outside air (and I have not seen one in this country that is), using it will increase you heating bill if you expect to maintain 70F in the house. The reason is because a fire will draw massive amounts of conditioned air up the chimney that needs to be replaced with cold air from the outside, through cracks, leaks, vents etc. While it feels warm in the immediate vicinity of the fireplace (stone/brick radiates the heat), keeping the rest of the house warm requires more energy.

Comment: Do you have the ability to upgrade to natural gas?  Natural gas furnaces are really efficient, you could likely cut your bill in half so you'd see ROI in just a few years.

Comment: Unfortunately this entire subdevelopment was built without natural gas service (relatively common in DFW for a house this age), so there isn't even a main to tap into. A retrofit involving a propane/NG tank and scheduled fills would be possible, but I think it would be more feasible, and overall more useful, to add some solar panels and reduce our metered draw that way.

Comment: Ouch.  And I get bent out of shape when my electric bill is over $30/month!  :-)

Comment: Well, like I said it's all-electric. So, my natural gas bill is zero. if I had a gas stove, oven, heater, clothes dryer, and HWH, and didn't use my microwave as much as I do, I'd probably be right there with ya on the electric, but I'd have $80 NG bills.

Comment: Your EDIT 2 should be written as the answer to this question.

Comment: @KeithS Really? I lived in DFW almost 20 years, and I never saw homes that didn't have natural gas -- only some apartment buildings.

Comment: How can an electric furnace be anything but 99+% efficient?

Comment: could you tell me the Lenox model you have? We've had same issues after buying a house with existing Lenox electric furnace. Bills in winter when temperature drops between 0-30 degrees have been around $700-800. Using over 8,000 kW each cycle

Comment: Note this is largely a perception problem,  OP is comiing from apartments/townhouses where (if the heat even was electric) there were shared walls.  When you have a shared wall with another unit, the other side of that wall is also 70 degrees and you don't lose any heat out of it.   Move to a house and suddenly your only neighbor is Old Man Winter.  And yes, electric is a stupid expensive way to heat a house.  Unless you're in one of those overnuked areas where they have favorable electric plans where they practically give away winter electricity.

Comment: Philadelphia area. 10x20 room with cathedral ceiling and skylights added over an unheated garage. Electric baseboard heating in the room. Sparing use of the electric heat with thermostat set to 65 can add another $100/month or so to the electrical bill in the winter just for that one room.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the DFW comment, I'm guessing you implied Dallas/Fort Worth. If that's the case, then you'll have AC already installed, and a lot of winter days that are above freezing. For that climate, a heat pump would be much more efficient. The emergency heat setting on a heat pump is the same as what you already have and you'll want to use that when it drops below freezing. But all other times the heat pump will be more efficient.

Comment: Modern cold-climate heatpumps can handle DFW's climate without emergency heat :P

Answer (score 6):

First, talk to your power company. Because in a community full of all electric homes, it's likely that the power company has plans (tariffs) for people like you, especially since you're in the sunbelt where their peak load is actually defined by air conditioning.   I've seen one power company tariff where the heating-season rate was "1 cent a kwh (!) plus $7/kw for your highest 30-minute period" (so that heater would add $110/month + $15/hour to your heating bill).

Unless something is broken, electric heat is 100% efficient.  It has no exhaust stack and there is literally nowhere else for the heat to go.  Every watt produces excatly 3.41 **BTU/hour** (which is the standard unit for HVAC, even though they call it "BTU" they mean BTU/hr).  However, there are two ways to go "over unity" without violating the laws of physics.

---

First, a *heat pump* is exactly what it says on the tin: it doesn't make heat, it only pumps heat.  You already have two in the house. One is the refrigerator.  The other is the air conditioner - it's a *one-way* heat pump, lacking the $6 reversing valve to be able to run backwards and heat. Stupid design.  Yes, heat pumps provide air conditioning.  The physics of heat are a little odd, and so this works: you can pump 2-6 BTUs of heat for energy cost of 1 BTU of electricity, so it is "over unity", often by quite a lot in favorable conditions. The best heat pumps are 38 SEER in cooling mode (loosely: 38 BTU/watt) and if you followed the above math of 3.41 BTU/watt, that's 11:1 over-unity.  Really.

Ground-sourced (or groundwater-sourced) heat pumps are <del>far</del> more efficient still, because they interchange heat with temperate underground areas.  **Edit: Better air-interchanging heat pumps [are really quite good these days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI&list=PLv0jwu7G_DFVIot1ubOZdR-KC-LFdOVqi&index=2). Chicago? No problem**.  But it can be said that they are always climbing uphill *(edit: unless you [run a clever schedule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI))*: in A/C mode, trying to dump heat into air that's already hot, or in heat mode, trying to extract heat from air thats already cold.  Ground or groundwater is always temperate.   <del>Ground-sourced pumps also won't need an emergency heat mode, which is plain resistance heating - exactly what you have now</del>.

Second, a resistance heating element doesn't need to be dumb.  It can be very, very smart, and be optimized for solving crypotgraphic problems, one of which is mining "BitCoins" or other digital currencies.  1 BTU of electricity only gives 1 BTU  of heat, but it also gives you some digital currencies you can sell to offset the cost of electricity.  This won't be as profitable as the forums say, because you'd only run it when you want heat.  If you ran it year round, you'd be paying peak rates not only for electricity to run the miners, but to run the air conditioning to cool them.  OK, that's not over-unity *thermally* but it is over-unity *financially*.

---

Your house was built at a time when nuclear industry executives were promising that nuclear *fusion* would be "clean, safe, and too cheap to meter".  They were recommending America build out all-electric with all deliberate speed.  They never imagined $400 heating bills. But other technologies (like heat pumps, especially ground-sourced) or dual-use machines ease the burden.

Why is a house so much more brutal than an apartment or townhouse? Exposed sides.  In an apartment you have many walls in common with neighbors and 0 heat liss through those walls, because behind those walls is the same temperature.  In a house you have all 4 walls, roof and floor/crawlspace exposed, that plus your larger square footage (of floor area) means your square footage (of exposed surface) is many times larger than an apartment. And thats what you pay for.

Answer (score 5):

If your heating system has ducts running through the attic check to make sure one of them has not come loose. Blowing heat into the attic can keep the heater running a lot more than it should.

Comment: Years later but great point here. Also check for appropriate insulation while you're up in the attic checking the ducts.